How difficult would initializing spin qubits at room temperature be?
I am researching the Australian company, Archer Material's, room temperature quantum computing chip development. They are pursuing ESR quantum computing at room temperature using carbon nanospheres for the qubit.
Below is a paper on their qubit as well as a simple explanation for how their chip might work. Also I have linked to an article on the "pulsed-ESR" technology being used.
My question is: Are there known ways to initialize spin qubits at room temperature, or would entirely new techniques need to be researched and developed? I am trying to learn how difficult this might be.
My understanding is that spin qubits systems rely on thermal Boltzmann population and T1 relaxation to provide polarization. In order to get close to a pure starting state one needs to go to very high fields(>3T) and very low temperature (<4K)
https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07690
https://archerx.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/20240325_Archer-and-EPFL-develop-a-single-chip-pulsed-ESR-microsystem-ASX-Release.pdf

